# Wordpress Woocommerce New Order Email is send to default (admin's) email as well as the new (receipient text box value ) email address

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

In wordpress woocommerce new order mail recipient changed to new email address but the mail goes to the default as well as new mail address. please help

Initially the Woocommerce new order mail recipient is the admin's email address. but now I have changed the recipient's email address to the manager's email address from Woocommerce > Settings > Emails > New Order > Recipient. After that the new order mails are send to the manager's email address its OK.

But also same mails are send to the admin's address which I don't want.
Help me to prevent new order mail sending to the admin's email

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to `hard-code` this. Add this to your functions.php file from your child theme and change the email inside the `''` to the email you like. Try it out and tell me if it works:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'custom_new_order_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function custom_new_order_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {

    //Return custom recipient email
    return 'custom@example.com';
}
```

If it works, we can change function that the email is taken from the email input field you mentioned in your question.